# Is gRPC connection always sticky when connecting to a kubernates service which is served from multiple pods?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, grpc-java

I have an application that provides a gRPC service for many clients which are using gRPC streams. In my application design i need only one instance of the application to be run as there is an application side dependency to send sequential gRPC requests only to one service.

Now i need to introduce another replica of my application. This is only for quick failover in any application failure, not for load balancing. I still need my all gRPC requests to be served only from on replica of my application and other replica should just up and running as a standby component.

I have seen many references that gRPC in Kubernates acts as sticky connections and many people want to overcome this for load balancing. But here i do not want to overcome this and i want to use that sticky nature for my requirement.

So my question is when i create a gRPC stream connection, can i guarantee that the connection is always sticky? If not i may face some application level errors.

Comment: According to this [blog](https://majidfn.com/blog/grpc-load-balancing/),if there is failure in connection it will force the client to send a new request to the load balancer and as a response to this request this time a healthier instance will be returned and stickiness might not sustain.

Answer (score 2):

With the default client-side load balancer (`pick_first`), gRPC makes a single connection and uses it as long as it is functional. If it disconnects, then the connection is re-created.

gRPC does not notify the application when the connection is replaced. Sometimes the connection fails abruptly and some RPCs fail, but other times the replacement is seamless, other than a bit of added latency.

Generally the recommendation is to use a single stream for the communications needing strong affinity. A stream is bound to a single backend, so if the connection dies the streaming RPC will fail. That provides a notification to your application that the affinity may have been lost. This approach works even with L7 load balancing where every RPC may go to a different backend.

`pick_first` by its nature does provide affinity across RPCs. But it is weak affinity. That is great for keeping caches warm. You could leverage it, but your application should still be prepared for the case the connection moves to another backend and determine how you want to resolve the errors it would cause. After all, that is exactly what would happen during a failover event.